# Ribbon workbench is add automatically two commands after publishing

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016, crm-ribbon-workbench

Whenever I add button using ribbon workbench button it will add successfully but when I add second button after first time publish that time is error is accoutered.

> Error is: Command ID is Duplicate

During adding button process I was adding only one button and one command but after publishing ribbon workbench add two commands on the same button.

Comment: Which version Of RWB? Pls add screenshots..

Comment: I am using latest version of Ribbon workbench 3.1.177.1

Comment: If you’re sure about it, report the issue here: https://ribbonworkbench.uservoice.com/forums/155731-general

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug was introduced & fixed later.

> The resolution for this should now be available, our current build number is 9.1.0.2437.
>   I've tested editing the ribbonDiffXml which worked fine, and then creating and deleting a command and button in Ribbon Workbench - both actions also worked with no problem.

[Read more](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/310529)